# Alias table that's actually a pivoted one?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have this query:

```
SELECT
    A.USERID 
    A.NAME
    PVT.PHONE 'PROBABLY A CASE STATEMENT ON NULL WILL GO HERE...
    PVT.ADDRESS 'ON HERE AS WELL...
FROM
    USERS A
    'I NEED TO CREATE A PIVOT TABLE HERE WITH THE ALIAS OF 'PVT' ON TABLE 'B'
```

B Contents:

```
 UserID  PHONE          ADDRESS      TYPE
 1       444-555-2222   XXXXXXX      PHONE
 1       XXXXXXX        66 Nowhere   NOTADDRESS
```

I want, on the same row, the user's phone by getting B.PHONE if TYPE = 'PHONE'.

I also want, on the same row, the user's address by getting B.ADDRESS content if TYPE = 'ADDRESS'.

As you see in the table dump above, I **don't** have a record matching the **user ID** AND **TYPE = 'ADDRESS'**

So I would need to show a blank or 'No address' in the main SELECT which will show the phone, but on the same row, blank or 'No address'.

I don't want to create an INNER JOIN because if there are no matching UserID's in B, the query will not return the info that I have in table A for that user.

Also, a LEFT JOIN will create two rows, which I don't want.

I think I pivoted table as alias would do it, but I don't know how to create such an alias.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using conditional aggregation?

```
SELECT A.USERID, A.NAME
       B.PHONE, B.ADDRESS
FROM USERS A LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT UserId, MAX(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'PHONE' THEN PHONE END) as PHONE,
             MAX(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'ADDRESS' THEN ADDRESS END) as ADDRESS
      FROM B
      GROUP BY UserId
     ) B
     ON B.UserId = A.UserId;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you *have* to use PIVOT then you'd need the pivot in a subquery and left join to it

```
SELECT
    A.USERID,
    A.NAME,
    PVT.PHONE,
    PVT.[ADDRESS]
FROM
    Users A
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
                FROM 
                   (SELECT 
                        UserID, 
                        [Type],
                        (CASE [Type] WHEN 'PHONE' THEN PHONE WHEN 'ADDRESS' THEN [Address] END) Info 
                    FROM UserInfo) AS UI
                PIVOT (
                    MAX(Info)
                    FOR [Type] IN ([PHONE], [ADDRESS])
                ) P
    ) PVT ON A.UserID = PVT.UserID
```

This gives you pretty much the same execution plan as the conditional aggregation query, but not as easy on the eyes.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91907b/1)